# ngcsv - Trouble in safari and IE Browsers

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, csv, safari

I am using Angular js to load table in my page. Now i want to export the data to excel. For that i find a solution of using ngcsv. It is mentioned as it can easily convert json array to .csv file. I tried with that and got succeeded in Firefox and Chrome Browser. But in safari and IE it is not working. 
  I tried the following fiddler example given in internet

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/asafdav/dR6Nb/`
```

It is also not working in Safari and IE. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no workaround as such, unless you decide to write your own library.

On the github page of ng-csv : https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv

It is clearly stated that Safari is not supported and only IE 10+ are supported.